# Question on the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$

Tags: exponential-function, functional-equations

> Are there any functions other than $a^{kx}$ that satisfy the relation $$f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)\text?$$

Actually I have a question that states that there exists a function such that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and $f(5) =2$, $f'(0)=3$, then $f'(5)=$?
I thought of assuming the function as $a^{kx}$ and proceeded but I don't get my solution right.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation

Comment: If you add the condition that f be *continuous* then the answer is "no".

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to solve this equation. Just compute:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x+y) = f'(x+y)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[f(x)f(y)\right] = f'(x)\cdot f(y)
$$
Equate these two and set $x=0$, $y = 5$  to find:
$$
f'(5) = f'(0)\cdot f(5) = 3\cdot 2 = 6
$$

Comment: Why did you put f'(y)=0? And why is my method incorrect when I have enough conditions to generate the function itself?

Comment: I didn't do that. Reread my response.
Your method would work if you did all the algebra correctly, but it is overkill.